# Understanding signal blocking and signal suspension

Tags: c, unix, signals

After reading the documentation I still don't really understand signal blocking. If you have a mask that blocks a given signal, do you need to unblock that signal first to allow the program to intercept it or does signal blocking behave in a different way?

If you use sigsuspend, does your program get suspended until a given signal from the mask you pass as an argument arrives?

Should the signal you wait for when using sigsuspend be unblocked or is it not necessary?

Btw i am using C and the pthread library to write my programs

Comment: Yes, the whole point of blocking is that if a signal is blocked, it won't be delivered, but remain pending.  Your program won't run the handler or do anything else until the signal is unblocked.  As for sigsuspend, [the Linux man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigsuspend.2.html) explains under "Notes" that the signal should be *blocked* before you call sigsuspend.  It will be unblocked by sigsuspend itself.

Comment: @NateEldredge under notes it also says that I should call sigsuspend using the "old set", if I understand this correctly, the old set would be the old mask before sigprocmasc was called (to recover it or something), which could contain every signal. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: If you want to wait for SIGFOO, first you use `sigprocmask` to block SIGFOO.  Then you call `sigsuspend` with a mask that does *not* include SIGFOO - such as the "old mask" that `sigprocmask` returned.

Comment: The key is that this avoids a race condition.  Suppose you know that SIGFOO is going to be sent exactly once.  Your code wants to wait for it with `sigsuspend` and then go on to do some work.  If SIGFOO wasn't blocked before the call to `sigsuspend`, it might arrive right before the `sigsuspend` call.  It's too late for your code to change your mind about calling `sigsuspend`, so the `sigsuspend` goes ahead - and now it waits forever because the signal already arrived and won't be sent again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you have a mask that blocks a given signal, do you need to unblock that signal first to allow the program to intercept it or does signal blocking behave in a different way?

A signal is never delivered to any thread that has it blocked.  If a signal is raised for a process while all threads of that process have it blocked, then it remains pending until it is unblocked for at least one thread, or the process terminates.

> If you use sigsuspend, does your program get suspended until a given signal from the mask you pass as an argument arrives?

No.  The signal mask you pass to `sigsuspend` has the same meaning as the one you pass to (for example) `sigprocmask()`: it specifies a complete set of the signals that should be blocked.  This mask must not include any signals you want the thread to be able to receive.  Often, it is appropriate to pass `sigsuspend()` the mask that was in effect prior to a preceding `sigprocmask()` call, which the latter function will have provided to you if you asked for it.

> Should the signal you wait for when using sigsuspend be unblocked or is it not necessary

At all times, you should ensure that any signal you want a thread to be able to receive is unblocked, and conversely, that any signal the thread must not receive is blocked.  This is why `sigsuspend()` gives you a way to specify a different signal mask to be in effect for the duration of the call.