# sigsuspend turns process into zombie instead of puting it to sleep

Tags: c

My program creates multiple processes, the parent process will send SIGUSR1 to all child processes with the following function:

```
void sendtochild (struct system_ system, int sig) {
    pid_t selfpid = getpid();

    for (int i = 0; i < system.children; i++) {
        if (system.pids[i] != selfpid && system.pids[i] != system.parent) {
            kill(system.pids[i], sig);
        }
    }
}
```

The signal gets awaited in the following way:

```
    sigset_t set, oset;

    sigemptyset(&set);
    sigaddset(&set, SIGUSR1);
    if (sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &set, &oset) < 0) {
        perror("sigprocmask");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    printf("%d ", getpid());
    fflush(stdout);
    
    sigsuspend(&oset);
```

for some reason when looking at top the children are zombies instead of sleeping until the signal is delivered which is not the behavior I'm looking for.

Comment: [mcve] please.  Has the child installed a handler for `SIGUSR1`?  If not, its default action is to terminate the process, which would cause exactly the behavior you describe: child has terminated, and parent hasn't `waitpid`'d for it, so it remains a zombie.

Comment: Also, to avoid the race condition I mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71548009/understanding-signal-blocking-and-signal-suspension#comment126454560_715480090), in between blocking the signal and calling `sigsuspend`, you have to check whether the signal has already arrived (e.g. by testing a flag that the signal handler would have set).  Either that, or you have to ensure that the signal was blocked before it could possibly have been sent.  The simplest way would be to block it before forking off the children; they inherit the parent's signal mask.

Comment: In fact, you do have to either block the signal and/or install the handler before forking.  If you try to do it in the child, there is always the chance that it takes too long and hasn't finished by the time the signal is sent - in which case it will be terminated.

Comment: @NateEldredge — good information; I recommend converting your comments into an answer (all except the mention of MRE).